# NSString from NSString to set as key in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am getting a **initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]** at the following line:

```
[contentsOfCocktails setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: recipeTitleA] forKey:cocktailsTitleA];
```

`recipeTitleA` is the string I'm creating from the `cocktails.recipeID` class property that equals A. However, I am getting a `recipeTitleA` equals **nil** in the debug window.

Here is where I set `cocktails.recipeID` equal to `recipeTitleA`:

```
if ([cocktails.recipeID isEqualToString:@"A"]){
    recipeTitleA = cocktails.recipeID;
}
```

**Is this the correct way to set a string equal to another string in order to use it as a key in a NSMutableDictionary?**

Long story short: I am trying to extract the recipeIDs that equal A and set them as a key in a dictionary. I will be doing this with other letters as keys as well. I was then going to store them in an array in which I could create sections in the tableview. Data is brought in with FMDB.

I'm new to obj-c and new to data formatting with arrays and dictionaries. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the debugger is telling you that `recipeTitleA` is nil, that means it's nil, or you can't add nil in an array. So you have to find why it's nil, your way to setting up your `NSMutableDictionnary` is good.

Comment: Is 'cocktails.recipeID' nil? Where to you set that?

Comment: @Ckouta I looked all over the place, and I believe the entire cocktails class is loading as nil. Could it be because I don't get the data with FMDB until further down in tableviewcontroller? I allocate and initialize Cocktails above the given code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing the string comparison correctly.  Set a breakpoint at `if ([cocktails.recipeID isEqualToString:@"A"]){` and see what you are getting for `cocktails.recipeID`, if it's **nil** go back into your `cocktails.recipeID` property and look if its being set correctly.

Comment: It looks like the class 'Cocktails' is loading as nil on that line, which is weird considering I allocated and initialized it right above. And I called [self recipeCocktails] right above that. `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *recipeID` is how it is declared in Cocktails.h... so I assume it's being set correctly.